# What are conditions to get NPC invasion at Dark Souls 3?

Tags: dark-souls-3

**What are conditions to get NPC invasion at Dark Souls 3?**

I saw invastion by [Holy Knight Hodrick](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Holy+Knight+Hodrick) in [this video](https://youtu.be/MnU3luuxQ6E?list=PLcdPu6JrcV8RrIiD6ECjcjZjm5eUK-5Co&t=1079), so I tried to reproduce it. I went to this area and ate Ember... and nothing happend, I waited for 5 minutes at the point the invasion happened in the video, then walked pretty much everywere around this point and still - nothing.
So I wonder what are all conditions to get invaded by NPC? Do you need to play online, for example (because I don't)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two requirements to be invaded by NPCs: You need to be embered and the area boss needs to still be alive.

If the invasion doesn't happen, you probably already defeated the boss. In the Undead Settlement that would be the Curse-Rotted Greatwood. Whether you play online or offline doesn't affect NPC invasions and if you die, you will be invaded again in the same place until you defeat the invader or kill the boss. If you already killed the boss, the only way to get the invasion on the same character is to play through the game a second time in New Game+.

Comment: Great answer for the general case, but I think it's worth noting that some NPCs have very specific quest requirements. As far as I know Holy Knight Hodrick doesn't have any additional requirements, but Pale Shade of Londor does for example.